# flutter_web how to implement RECAPTCHA?

Tags: flutter, recaptcha, flutter-web

I am completely stuck on how to implement RECAPTCHA with flutter_web.

The current available plugins (https://pub.dev/packages/recaptchav2_plugin and https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_recaptcha_v2) do not support web.

Comment: I hope this link will help: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60935660)

Comment: Thanks @hisam. So pointing to our own RECAPTCHA hosted on our domain, through a web view in the app. Wondering if there are any alternative ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the major steps to test the `g_recaptcha_v3` package extracted from the article [implementation of Google reCAPTCHA v3 in Flutter Web](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-implement-google-recaptcha-v3-in-flutter-web-38000139bbc0).

1. Register your site via the [Google reCAPTCHA Admin Console](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about).

[image: Google reCAPTCHA v3 Site Registration Form]

2. Add the required `pubspec` packages.

```dart
  # A composable, Future-based library for making HTTP requests.
  http: ^0.13.4

  # A Google reCAPTCHA is a free service that protects your website from spam and abuse.
  g_recaptcha_v3: ^0.0.4
```

3. Navigate to the `web` folder, open the `index.html` file and paste the below script inside the `<body>` tag.

```js
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=recaptcha-site-key"></script>
```

4. Add the `GRecaptchaV3.ready` in the `main`method and run the app.

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await GRecaptchaV3.ready('recaptcha-site-key');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

[image: Counter App with Google reCAPTCHA protection]

Comment: need to verify user's response https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: on your post, I have question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75513855/how-t