# how can i called function wrote in flutter with dart , from javascript?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

> I build flutter app with just webview to show my website , i need to
> access to specific method in flutter app from javascript , Ex: to show
> some dialog in app .

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the WebViewExample plugin you're using, you'll need to use `JavascriptChannel`.

You can find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53689662/flutter-webview-two-way-communication)

***UPDATE***

Since the OP is using [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview), [this](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/370)contains all the information to use Javascript channels with the plugin.

Comment: i need to access from javascript to method wrote in flutter , like popup 'share' in whatsapp , facebook , or copy link .after click in button share in website in my app .

Comment: heh yes, via the JavascriptChannels you can call, from JS, methods written in dart

Comment: Sorry, but is there any way with using InAppWebView .

Comment: yup, check this out! https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/370! There's an example too

Comment: I have updated the answer with the link